# I am trying t create a login/logout functionality in django but am getting follow error

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

Hi i am trying to create a login/logout functionality in django ,i have been trying for some time now but am getting the following error please help me out i am new to all Django.I have done everything as taught in the course but am still getting this error,i think error is in url file but i don't really know.

```
    Using the URLconf defined in TheResources.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    
    ^$ [name='index']
    admin/
    ^FirstApp/ ^user_login/$ [name='user_login']
    login/ [name='login']
    logout/ [name='logout']
    password_change/ [name='password_change']
    password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
    password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
    password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']
    reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
    reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']
    ^logout/$ [name='logout']
    The current path, FirstApp/user_login/{url 'FirstApp::user_login'}, didn't match any of these.
    
    URL.py project
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^FirstApp/',include('FirstApp.url')),
        path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
        url(r'^logout/$',views.user_logout,name='logout'),
    
    Url .py application file
    url(r'^Registration/$',views.RegistrationView,name='Registration'),
    url(r'^user_login/$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
    
    Views.py file
    
    def user_login(request):
    
        if request.method=='POST':
            username=request.POST.get('username')
            password=request.POST.get('password')
    
            user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    
            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("account is not active")
    
            else:
                 print("Someone else tried to login and failed")
                 return HttpResponse("Invalid credentials")
        else:
             return render (request,'FirstApp/Base.html',{})
     
    Temlplate
    Base.html 
    {%if user.is_authenticated%}
       <a href="{%url 'logout'%}">Logout</a>
       {%else%}
       <a href="{%url 'FirstApp:user_login'%}">login</a>
    {%endif%}
    
    Login.html file
    <form action="{url 'FirstApp::user_login'}" method='POST'>
          {%csrf_token%}
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="Password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
          <input type="Submit" value="Login">
        </form>
```

Comment: You are missing full jinja tag on <form action="{url 'FirstApp::user_login'}"

Comment: iklinac thanks a lot you are right everything has worked out fine now,thnks a lot